# Multiple observers on an entity

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

Is it possible to call different observables from the same object separately?

So that if  an entity  has observable A and B, i could call one without calling the other?
or pass some data back so that when i call A , B will ignore the notification.

Comment: [Please improve your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What's the point of declaring observable B on an object if you're not going to call it ? Sounds like a design flaw

Comment: You're absolutely right, no point in me doing it. Im going to just use something like the strategy pattern instead and have that contact the observer.